# SQL Server - Combining a date field, a literal character and a DATEADD value in a case statment

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, dateadd

I’ve created a case statement to work in this order.

Determine if it’s a “Priority Escalation”, “Ready for Pickup”, “Waiting for Routing”, ELSE a date range.

The above works if I exclude the `ELSE` portion of the case statement.  If none of the other cases are true, then I need my else statement to produce a Shipment Date  plus 2 days added to the Shipment date to give a date range for when a package will be shipped.   i.e.   `02/15/2016 – 02/17/2016`

```
Select
    Case 
        When datediff (day, sl.[Shipment Date], sl.[Priority Escalation Date]) < 0 then  'Priority Escalation'
        When sh.[On Hold] = 'RFP' then 'Ready for Pickup'
        When sh.[On Hold] = 'WFR' then 'Waiting for Routing'
        Else sl.[Shipment date] + “ – “ + & DateAdd("d", 2, sl.[Shipment Date]) 
    End as 'Expected Value'
```

This is what the data should look like

```
Expected Value
02/24/2016 - 02/26/2016
02/24/2016 - 02/26/2016
02/24/2016 - 02/26/2016
02/24/2016 - 02/26/2016
Waiting for Routing
Waiting for Routing
Priority Escalation
Ready for Pickup
Ready for Pickup
Priority Escalation
Priority Escalation
Priority Escalation
Ready for Pickup
```

Comment: Where is your sample data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be running into a conversion error. To fix that, you need to `CONVERT` your dates to `VARCHAR`:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF (DAY, sl.[Shipment Date], sl.[Priority Escalation Date]) < 0 THEN  'Priority Escalation'
        WHEN sh.[On Hold] = 'RFP' THEN 'Ready for Pickup'
        WHEN sh.[On Hold] = 'WFR' THEN 'Waiting for Routing'
        ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), sl.[Shipment date], 101) + ' - ' 
                + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, 2, sl.[Shipment Date]), 101) 
    END AS 'Expected Value'
```

Comment: Thank you Felix!  I appreciate the quick response and want you to know that it now works that way I need it to.